# PHP match string in array, modify string and then create new array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm not sure how to better phrase my question, but here is my situation.

I have an array like the following:

```
$temp_array = array("111111-Name1-122874|876394|120972", "222222-Name2-122874|876394|120972", "333333-Name3-122874|876394|120972");
```

I need to loop through this array and try to match the first portion of each string in the array

e.g.

```
$id          = "222222";
$rand_number = "999888";
if ($id match the first element in string) {
     fetch this string
     append "999888" to "122874|876394|120972"
     insert this string back to array
}
```

So the resulting array becomes:

```
$temp_array = array("111111-Name1-122874|876394|120972", "222222-Name2-999888|122874|876394|120972", "333333-Name3-122874|876394|120972");
```

Sorry if my question appears confusing, but it really is pretty difficult for me to even grasp some of the required operations.

Thanks

Comment: purely based on the above - `foreach()` loop, `substr()` to match then create a new output array appended extra data.

Comment: append or prepend? you said one but your example shows the other?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, prepend or append is actually both fine in my case

Comment: i think all 3 of us have a version of right - pick one :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$temp_array = array("111111-Name1-122874|876394|120972", "222222-Name2-122874|876394|120972", "333333-Name3-122874|876394|120972");
$id          = "222222";
$rand_number = "999888";

// Loop over each element of the array
// For each element, $i = the key, $arr = the value
foreach ($temp_array as $i => $arr){

    // Get the first characters of the element up to the occurrence of a dash "-" ...
    $num = substr($arr, 0, strpos($arr, '-'));

    // ...and check if it is equal to $id...
    if ($num == $id){
        // ...if so, add $random_number to the back of the current array element
        $temp_array[$i] .= '|'  . $rand_number;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 111111-Name1-122874|876394|120972
    [1] => 222222-Name2-122874|876394|120972|999888
    [2] => 333333-Name3-122874|876394|120972
)
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/eXrCiXXt)

Note: As Dagon pointed out in his comment, your question says *appends*, but your example shows the data being *prepended*. This method appends, but can be altered as necessary.

---

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: thanks a ton for the reply, I tried your code and it works great, but I would really like to better understand this code. Are you able to provide a little explanation? Thanks :)

Comment: @user2028856 I've added some comments to the code that might help explain it a little.

Comment: What does the .= symbol mean? I've seen it elsewhere but couldn't find out what it means

Comment: @user2028856 It's for string concatenation; it appends to the string rather than overwriting it. If `$x = 'hello'`, and you said `$x .= 'world'`, then `$x` would contain `helloworld`. [Consider this demo](http://codepad.org/tFkBcDkq)

Comment: its an Assignment Operator: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php

Answer (score 2):

crude answer - its going to depend on the expected values of the initial ids. if they could be longer or shorter then explode on the hyphen instead of using substr

```
    $temp_array = array("111111-Name1-122874|876394|120972","222222-Name2-122874|876394|120972","333333-Name3-122874|876394|120972");

    $id = "222222";
    $rand_number = "999888";

    foreach($temp_array as $t){
        if(substr(0,6,$t)==$id){
            $new[] = $t.'|'.$rand_number;
        }else{
            $new[] = $t;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also using some exploding in this case too:

```
$temp_array = array("111111-Name1-122874|876394|120972", "222222-Name2-122874|876394|120972", "333333-Name3-122874|876394|120972");
$id = "222222";
$rand_number = "999888";
foreach($temp_array as &$line) {
                    // ^ reference
    $pieces = explode('|', $line); // explode pipes
    $first = explode('-', array_shift($pieces)); // get the first part, explode by dash
    if($first[0] == $id) { // if first part is equal to id
        $first[2] = $rand_number; // replace the third part with random
        $first = implode('-', $first); // glue them by dash again
        $line = implode('|', array($first, implode('|',$pieces))); // put them and glue them back together again
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($temp_array);
```

Comment: This code works also well, except that I don't want to replace the third part with random, I just want to append the new random number to the existing random number string

Comment: @user2028856 actually, looking at the resultant array, it seems that that part is replaced by the random, so the real intent really is to append/push it on the end when the match occurs

Answer (score 2):

Another version using [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

```
$temp_array = array("111111-Name1-122874|876394|120972", "222222-Name2-122874|876394|120972", "333333-Name3-122874|876394|120972");

$id          = "222222";
$rand_number = "999888";
$params = array('id'=>$id, 'rand_number'=>$rand_number);
array_walk($temp_array, function(&$value, $key, $param){
    $parts = explode('-', $value); // Split parts with '-' so the first part is id
    if ($parts[0] == $param['id']){
        $parts[2]="{$param['rand_number']}|{$parts[2]}"; //prepend rand_number to last part
        $value=implode('-',$parts); //combine the parts back
    }
},$params);

print_r($temp_array);
```

If you just want to append The code becomes much shorter

```
$params = array('id'=>$id, 'rand_number'=>$rand_number);
array_walk($temp_array, function(&$value, $key, $param){
    // here check if the first part of the result of explode is ID 
    // then append the rand_number to the value else append '' to it.
    $value .= (explode('-', $value)[0] == $param['id'])? "|{$param['rand_number']}" : '';
},$params);
```

Edit: Comments added to code.